# How do I load images / assets from Images.xcassets in ReactJS Native?

Tags: ios, jsx, reactjs-native

I have images placed the usual way in Xcode's Images.xcassets for my ReactJS Native project. However, I don't know the syntax to reference a PNG from an `<Image />`.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html gives an example syntax of:

```
  <Image
    style={styles.icon}
    source={require('image!myIcon')}
  />
```

If I have a foo.png immediately under Images.xcassets, how can I properly reference it from React Native?

Comment: Are you seeing the expected image or not? That is not clear in your question. Also, there is a note making sure to rebuild the project when adding image assets: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#adding-static-resources-to-your-app-using-images-xcassets

Comment: I am not seeing the expected image.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `uri` as referenced [here](https://%EF%BB%BFhttps://reactnative.dev/docs/images#images-from-hybrid-apps-resources).

If the image name is 'foo.png' you just need to use the following syntax

```
<Image
   style={styles.icon}
   source={{ uri:'foo' }} // without extension ".png"
 />
```

Notice that, you don't have to put the extension of the file.